# How to still load vueRouter routes on bwowser refresh?

Tags: php, vue.js, vue-router

I have a project which is based on php request. but i have some routes generated by vueRouter.
The problem is that when i am visting the page generated by vouRouter and try to refresh the page it's take me to 404 page. How can i fix this problem. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Hi Darcy, I think you might get more help for this issue if you have the opportunity to add some code to your question. Maybe some code especially related to the issue that is happening.

Comment: Is the 404 page being returned by the vue app or by your underlying web server?

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache. app depends on your server mang. you wanna pass php to fastpass and anything else to a nginx spa config.

Comment: Configure your server. Read this: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: The 404 page is generated by the web server.

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations. I think this configuration is for a vue cli project. I am using apache server and the app is serving in a public subfolder